# Styling a select dropdown with JS and CSS breaks functionality

Tags: javascript, select

I wanted to style my dropdown select menu with CSS and I found this code

After adding all the code, the styling works, but the functionality of the dropdown select is broken, it doesn't work anymore.

I got the code from w3schools. Can you point out the Javascript issue that is causing the problem?

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/* Look for any elements with the class "custom-select": */
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item: */
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list: */
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 0; j < ll; j++) {
    /* For each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item: */
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /* When an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item: */
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /* When the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box: */
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box: */
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

/* If the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes: */
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none;
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I added HTML from w3schools and it seems to work?

Comment: w3schools is not an excellent resource...

Comment: Maybe a link to the actual page would be more helpful? I know this is not welcome on StackOverflow, but since it's implemented in a Wordpress website, I don't see how I can explain it more clearly that it breaks the dropdown functionality without showing the actual page.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Did you call the div the same as w3schools did?

Comment: There are no errors in the Console. The JS code is implemented as you see it. I changed `for (i = 0; i < sl; i++)` from the original code because the original was i=1 and it was hiding the first line in the dropdown (as I read elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site has more than one select so to use the values of the selects, you can do this

```js
const vals = [...document.querySelectorAll(".pt-cv-wrapper .cvp-dropdown")]
  .map(sel => sel.querySelector('.select-selected').textContent)
  .filter(val => !val.startsWith("Select"));

if (vals.length > 0) {
  console.log("Filtering on " + vals.join(", "))
  document.querySelectorAll(".pt-cv-ifield")
    .forEach(div => div.hidden = [...div.querySelectorAll(".terms a")]
      .filter(link => vals.includes(link.title)).length === 0)
```

Comment: THANKS! I can take it from here. Please delete the jsfiddle since this is a private section that is not yet lauched. The rest of the answer ca remain, it's pretty clear to me and will accept is as a solution. Thanks again!